# how to compute the symplectic form of Symplectic submanifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, manifolds, symplectic-geometry, submanifold

Consider a n-dimensional manifold $M$. Suppose I have a constraint on $M$ that defines a submanifold $N\subset M$:

$$ F:M\longrightarrow \mathbb{R} $$ $$ N:=\{p\in M \ | \ F(p)=0 \} \subset M$$

The cotangent bundle $T^*M$ is a symplectic manifold with symplectic form given, in Darboux coordinates, by:

$$\omega = \sum_{i=1}^n dq_i\wedge dp_i$$

when introducing local coordinates on $M$: $(U;q_1,\cdots,q_n)$, with associated local coordinates on $T^*M$: $(T^*U;q_1,\cdots,q_n,p_1,\cdots,p_n)$

My question is simple: Is there a systematic way to write down the symplectic form on $T^*N$ in terms of the old one?

Comment: If you pick local coordinates $(q_1,\ldots,q_n)$ adapted to $N$ (so $N$ is given locally by $q_n=0$, and $(q_1,\ldots,q_{n-1})$ form coordinates on $N$), then the symplectic form on $T^*N$ is just $\omega_N = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}dq^i\wedge dp_i$. I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, though. There's no canonical way to embed $T^*N$ in $T^*M$. However if you pick such a (non-canonical) embedding $i:T^*N\to T^*M$, then $\omega_N = i^*\omega$.